# Tailscale device is connecting

Tags: raspberry-pi, tailscale

i installed tailscale in my raspberry pi which has rasbian bullseye 32 bit os in it , i connected my laptop to tailscale with that same email connected with pi ,now in tailscale admin console i opned in my laptop it shows that my pi is connected ,but when i moved my pi and laptop to a diffrent network /router it don't show connected , i can't access my pi through tailscale ip , and both my laptop and pi is connected with that network ?

i was trying to connect my devices through tailscale even though they are connected to diffrent networks, and i was hoping to connect my pi through vnc through tailscale ip wherever and whichever network it connect.